# VBA 2010 - AutoFilter Contains Variable

Tags: vba, variables, contains

I have this code:  Range("$A$1:$C$118").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*searchtext*"
Where searchtext needs to be a variable and am struggling to find out how to write it with a variable there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the value of the variable to the 'Criteria1' parameter.

Currently you're just sending the autofilter a string literal of "=searchtext".

Example:

```
Dim myCriteria as String

myCriteria = "ThisIsVariable"
Range("$A$1:$C$118").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myCriteria
```